# XmlReader : data invalid exception

Tags: c#, filestream, xmlreader

I'm trying to read an XML file and I get an XmlException : "data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1".

Here is the content of the XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
 <Materials override="TRUE">
  <Material name="" diffuse="" />
 </Materials>
</root>
```

And here is my code :

```
using (FileStream fstr = File.OpenRead(sFullPath))
{
  XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
  settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
  fstr.Position = 0;
  using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fstr, settings))
  {                    
     while (xmlReader.Read())
     {

     }
  }
}
```

The exception is raised by the call to Read().

I've been searching for an answer on different sites, had a look at the MSDN too, but can't solve my problem.

My code is taken from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/318876/Using-the-XmlReader-class-with-Csharp but I tried different snippets too.

I also checked the encoding of my file on Notepad++, tried both UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM, didn't make a change.

I'm stuck on this for a couple of days and I'm running out of ideas.
Thanx for your help!

Edit : removed the "..." in the snippet to avoid confusing people. I also did a try with :

```
using (XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(fstr))
```

and it appears that xmlReader.Encoding is returning null, whereas my file is encoded to UTF-8.

Comment: can you open the XML file in IE?  if not, then you have to fix the XML file

Comment: After removing the '...' from your XML sample it works like a charm.

Comment: @user2174714-1 Yes I can open it on a web browser. It says that there is not stylesheet associated and displays a correct tree.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit I skipped some XML datas in my snippet, as so in my code. In the real XML file there is no "...". And in my code, there is no "..." either.

Comment: What I mean is that we can't help you as the code and XML in the question just works. So you'll have to narrow down the problem a little. Perhaps try to copy paste the XML into a new file, or simplify the XML and build it up.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit I have tried different content in the XML file, different encoding too. I also did a simple test with `XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(sFullPath);`   where `sFullPath` is absolute path to a file. It appears that the creation of the `XmlTextReader` puts binary data into my XML file. That is why it fails to recognize the encoding and can't read it.

Comment: Ok I solved my issue. Problem was due to a call to a method of the SDK I'm using. It messes up the content of the file. Thanks for your feedbacks.